# Ajax "POST" is showing form entries in URL when pressing back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which get posted using POST to the same document and verified. When everything is verified the script redirects to another page. But when i click back from that page i can see all the form data within the URL like a GET request.

Here is the script for the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {    
        $("#ajaxform").on("submit", function( event )
        {
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();

            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache:false,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $("div.messagebox").html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

When everything is good i just do:  `echo '<script>window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");</script>';` in PHP. When pressing back after this the username and his password gets filled out in the URL. Obviously i do not want to show any of the user information inside the URL, or anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe the form is still submitting with a different method - try adding

return false;

to the end of your submit event just after the ajax call, other than that possibility I'm not seeing anything in your code that would cause that kind of behavior but maybe I'm just missing it. Try using the post function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: This seems to work. No time to really test it out but i will and give you the checkmark. What you mean with try using the "POST" function? I am using that finction... what?

Answer (score -1):

Reset the form in callback.

```
document.getElementById("#form").reset();
```

[link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) for more information.

Comment: This breaks the script. Also, I'm not sure that would get loaded when someone presses back.